# Did "brushwoodsmen" exist?

Tags: etymology, surnames

While talking to someone about surnames and ties to various jobs in the past ("Coopers" worked on barrels, "Smiths" made things, etc.) I asked about "Brushwood". He said that name tied to "brushwoodsmen", English thieves. I can't find any references on the term brushwoodsmen or brushwoodsman, though...are there references that such a thing existed?

Comment: Just going to throw this out here against notability, plenty of names aren't trades. Tons of German names mean things like "pretty lake" or other geographical/botanical things.

Comment: Other than this question and a Facebook account of someone who apparently fashions model Keyblades from the Kingdom Heart series, I'm having difficulty finding _any_ reference to "brushwoodsman" or "brushwoodsmen" on the web. "brushwood," on the other hand, leads to many results.

Comment: The fact that the word doesn't exist in the current Oxford English Dictionary in no way suggests that there wasn't an English dialect a few hundreds years in the past that had such a word.

Comment: [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=brushwood&searchmode=none) gives some ideas, all related to (sweeping) brushes or the plants they were made from. So the likely connection seems to be with either making brushes, or using them (cleaning).

Comment: Brushwood frequently derived from Coppicing: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppicing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only things I could find for the word *brushwoodsman* was a hit [Kath Trevelyan](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=4INlAAAAMAAJ&q=brushwoodsman&dq=brushwoodsman&hl=en&sa=X&ei=QNHvU7C5Kszo7AaYtoHgDw&redir_esc=y), by Jeremy Cooper, although the preview doesn't show it.

I thought I would try my luck and look for *brushwood men*. Surprisingly this actually worked.

The first thing I found was a bit disappointing. In the book [Sir Nigel](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=vBRFAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT208&dq=%22brushwood+men%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ZNLvU6KREIew7Aa314DoDA&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22brushwood%20men%22&f=false) (sorry, the link highlights the wrong thing, but the words are there):

[image: But the hatred and fear which its master had raised over the whole country-side could now be plainly seen, for during the night the brushwood men and the villagers came in from all parts with offers of such help as they could give for the intaking of the castle.]

The extract distinguishes "brushwood men" and *villagers*, so it must mean something, but it's not clear what.

An extract from [The White Company](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=XApEAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT253&dq=%22brushwood+men%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=0iPvU4z-IIPQ7Ab8iIHgAw&ved=0CC4Q6AEwATgK#v=onepage&q=%22brushwood%20men%22&f=false) came closer:

[image: Little they recked of the brushwood men who crouched in their rags along the fringe of the forest and looked with wild and haggard eyes at the rich warm glow which shot a golden bar of light from the high arched windows of the castle]

This clearly paints brushwood men as seemlying outcast, if not beggars.

(Both the above books are by Arthur Conan Doyle.)

But then I hit gold in [Tolkien the Medievalist](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=6TX3hJckf3YC&pg=PA99&dq=%22brushwood+men%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=AyPvU9KkGcSN7Qac94GIBQ&ved=0CEcQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=%22brushwood%20men%22&f=false):

[image: In life, which tends to be scruffier than literature, the outlaw type shows up in England as the brushwood men, in France as the Jacquierie, escaped serfs with nothing to lose, desperate men living wild because they could not risk a return to civilization.]

So You can see that brushwood men were indeed outlaws. Escaped serfs who would live in the forest and rob people to get by.

As is often the case back in those days, what someone is known to do would become their surname, so it is entirely plausible that *brushwood* would originate as a surname for the folk who can't live in the village and are outlaws.

I'd say it is equally plausible that the word *brushwoodsmen* is used in speech, if not writing, to indicate the same people.